# Sessions for logging in (PHP)?

Tags: php

I am having a bit of trouble getting my loggedin session to be set to true when the number of rows selected in my SQL query is > 0 and otherwise to be set to false. Whenever I input a valid login it does not print anything (I am printing it to check that it works) and when I put an invalid login in then it prints the session but loggedin has no value. I am also printing the username and password to check that the input is correct. I am new to PHP and web development in general and would appreciate any help! Thanks.

The PHP:

```
<?php

SESSION_START(); 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "MY USERNAME";
$password = "MY PASSWORD";
$dbname = "MY USERNAME";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$username = $_POST['usernameinput'];
$password= $_POST['passwordinput'];
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = false   ;

echo ($username); 
echo ($password);

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT `user-id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`     = '" . $username. "' AND `password` = '" . $password. "' ");

if (!$result) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['ID']; 
    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;  
 }     

print_r($_SESSION);

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain, what does return $row['ID'];  do?

Comment: Also, why `return`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php *"If called from within a function, the return statement immediately **ends execution** of the current function..."*

Comment: You also only selected the `user-id` column but not `ID`. So your code is failing on you on two counts.

Comment: I'm not sure why the return $row['ID]; I got that if statement from somehwhere online, should I take it out?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I took the return $row['ID'] out and the session is now set as 1, I'm assuming that that means true (1=True, 0=False). But when I input an invalid login it still prints Array ( [loggedin] =>). Does that mean false or should it be a 0?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = $row['user-id'];  
        print_r($_SESSION);
 }
 else {
        session_destroy();
        print 'Username or password is wrong.';
 }
```

In your case     `return $row['ID'];` is useless. Because your sql only selected `user-id`.